# Strongly p-embedded subgroups and p-Sylow subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ a prime number. Recall that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is strongly $p$-embedded if $p | \ |H|,$ and for each $x \in G \setminus H,$ $H \cap {^x}H$ has order prime to $p,$ where ${^x}H$ denotes the group we get after conjugation by $x.$  I am reading a proof which claims that any strongly $p$-embedded group contains a $p$-Sylow group of $G$. I can prove this fact by other means, but I would like to understand the proof I am reading. This is the argument I am reading:

Assume $H$ is strongly $p$-embedded. Since $p | \ |H|,$ $p$ contains an element $g$ of order $p.$ Choose any $S \in Syl_p(G)$ such that $g \in S.$ For $x \in Z(S)$ of order $p,$ $$g \in H \cap {^x}H$$ implies $x \in H.$ Hence for all $y \in S,$ $$x \in H \cap {^y}H $$ implies that $y \in H.$ Thus $S \subset H.$

Here is what I do not understand with the proof:

1. Why does it matter that $x \in Z(S)$ has order $p?$ It seems to me that for any $x \in Z(S),$ we have that $g \in H \cap {^x} H.$
2. Suppose I know that for $x \in Z(S)$ of order $p,$ $g \in H \cap {^x}H$ implies $x \in H,$ i.e. that the elements of order $p$ in $Z(S)$ is a subset of $H.$ Why does it follow then that if $y \in S$ is arbitrary, that $x \in H \cap {^y}H?$

Comment: I agree that for your first question the order of $x$ need not be equal to $p$.  But the second question I find a bit confusing.  Do you mean $Z(S)$ instead of $Z(P)$? If so, it seems to make sense.

Comment: @James Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I meant $Z(S).$ Does it make sense in the sense that you understand the argument of the proof, or in the sense that you understand my second question?

Comment: Well, I now understand the question and, I think, also the argument.  As per the first question, you need not restrict to elements of order $p$ so, in fact, we have $Z(S)\leq H$ from the first part of the argument. And, there exists, therefore, $1\neq t\in Z(S)$ (so $t$ is also an element of $H$). So, if $y$ is now any element in $S$, we have $t = t^y\in H\cap {}^{y}H$ and has $p$-power order, so $y$ must belong to $H$ by the assumption that $H$ is strongly $p$-embedded. This gives $S\leq H$.

Comment: Thanks, I misread the second statemnt and read it as $g \in H \cap {^y}H.$